# Laravel reverts to /public/ in URLs when trailing slashes are added

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my `.htaccess` in the root directory that's supposed to get rid of "public" from URLs:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my `.htaccess` in the public directory that's supposed to get rid of trailing slashes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This is all well and good, except that when I enter a URL with a trailing slash, it redirect back to a URL with no trailing slash, but also with `/public` added.

For example, we have this route:

```
Route::get('/de', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Normally, the URL looks like domain.com/de.

But, if I type in `domain.com/de/` into the browser, it redirects to `domain.com/public/de` instead of to `domain.com/de` - and the page loads as normal.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your site root .htaccess should be like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# route all requests to public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Then inside `public/.htaccess` have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if /public/ is part of original URL then remove it
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to completely clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: I already have all this, no? And when I try changing the DocumentRoot to /public I get an error saying "No input file specified"

Comment: `DocumentRoot` should still be pointing to parent directory of `public/`. Removal of trailing slash should be part of site root .htaccess and you must clear browser cache completely to test

Comment: Ok, done...but URLs with /public still work - they open the pages they're supposed to. How can I redirect them to versions without /public? Google has a bunch of links saved with /public and we're getting traffic there.

Comment: ok I have added a rule to remove `/public/` from URLs

Comment: I just loved the solution! That's what I have been searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Apache/Nginx should be pointing to the **public** directory instead of the **project root**.

This way you don't need to add any .htaccess rule to get rid of the "public" string in the URLs

Comment: When I do that, I get "No input file specified" when I try to open the website. I was following this guide: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/change-primary-domain-document-root-cpanelwhm/